# How to read data from xml of specific format

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to read xml as below using linq. I want to read all elements and their sub elements and values to use in to my code. For example I want to read ParameterID2, and its child elements and display those.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<labelled>
  <historyRecord recordedtime="12/12/1906">
    <ParameterID2>
      <parameterName>SWVersion</parameterName>
      <engineeringUnit>@@@</engineeringUnit>
      <previousValue>R1.2.3</previousValue>
    </ParameterID2>
    <ParameterID3>
      <parameterName>SWVersion</parameterName>
      <engineeringUnit>@@@</engineeringUnit>
      <previousValue>R1.2.3</previousValue>
    </ParameterID3>
    <ParameterID4>
      <parameterName>SWVersion</parameterName>
      <engineeringUnit>@@@</engineeringUnit>
      <previousValue>R1.2.3</previousValue>
    </ParameterID4>
    <ParameterID5>
      <parameterName>SWVersion</parameterName>
      <engineeringUnit>@@@</engineeringUnit>
      <previousValue>R1.2.3</previousValue>
    </ParameterID5>
  </historyRecord>      
</labelled>
```

I tried as code given below.

```
string xmlDocPath = "C:\\Users\\Dipak\\Desktop\\Documentation.xml";
string timestamp = "12/12/1906"; // this can vary
XDocument xmlDdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlDocPath);
var selectRecord = from recordS in xmlDdoc.Descendants("historyRecord").Where
                               (recordS => (string)recordS.Attribute("recordedtime") == timestamp)
                               select new
                               {
                                   parameterID1 = recordS.Element("ParameterID2").Name,
                                   // parameterID2 = recordS.Element("ParameterID3"),

                                   parameterName = recordS.Element("parameterName").Value,
                                   engineeringUnit = recordS.Element("engineeringUnit").Value,
                                   previousValue = recordS.Element("previousValue").Value,
                               };
```

Comment: So, what is your question now?  Does that code work?  If not, describe the problem. Post  error messages or expected vs actual outcomes.

Comment: It is not working. I want to store strings "ParameterID2" "ParameterID3" and all others and values of their child in local variables.

Comment: "is not working" is not a question anyone can answer.

Comment: when you go through the code in the debugger, what values do you get when calling `recordS.Element("XXX").Name` ?

Comment: selectRecord shows null.

Comment: When debugging, of course you tried to simplify your code. What was the result when you tried: `var x = XmlDdoc.Descendants("historyRecord").ToList()`? Did that give the results you expected? By the way, instead of answering to comments it is better to edit your original question, so readers won't have to browse through all the comments to grasp what you intended to ask

Comment: Change From : parameterID1 = recordS.Element("ParameterID2").Name To : parameterID1 = recordS.Descendents("ParameterID2").FirstOrDefault().Name